# What kind of DigitalOcean droplet should I use for my API. It is using php and mysql, involving all the mysql operations

Tags: php, mysql, api, digital-ocean

I am working on my startup and for our mobile app I'm creating an API. I need recommendation on where I should host it. I like DigitalOcean very much.

DigitalOcean have three kind of droplets: Standard, General Purpose, CPU-Optimized

My API is based on PHP and MySQL. It involves all the basic database actions. Not considering the traffic I just want to know which type of droplet I should use.

Know More about Droplets: https://www.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/

Answer (score 0):

My advice is standard droplets are good and cheaper for development and you can upgrade the same droplet for specifics after you are done with you api.

You might also want to use PhpMyAdmin droplet from the DigitalOcean Marketplace as it comes preset with php7 and mysql.